# How to create a type checker for multiple types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I created a type checker for primitives in TypeScript:

```
type PrimitiveType = 'undefined' | 'bigint' | 'boolean' | 'function' | 'number' | 'object' | 'string' | 'symbol';

export class TypeChecker {
  static isOneOf(value: unknown, ...types: (PrimitiveType|null)[]): value is PrimitiveType | null {
    const allowedTypes = new Set(types);
    return allowedTypes.has(typeof value) || allowedTypes.has(null) && value === null;
  }
}
```

Which can be used like:

```
const x: string|number|null = TypeChecker.isOneOf(value, 'string', 'number') ? value : null;
```

This works fine. However it will fail in this case as the compiler thinks its a match:

```
const x: string|null = TypeChecker.isOneOf(value, 'string', 'boolean') ? value : null;
```

How can I update the function so that it knows what types I asked for?

I'm currently using TS 5.0.2.

Comment: @depperm no, `is` and `asserts` means the function checks the type so TS may know the value type after the call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type TypeofMap = {
    "string": string
    "number": number
    "bigint": bigint
    "boolean": boolean
    "symbol": symbol
    "undefined": undefined
    "object": object
    "function": Function
    "null": null
}
//                                                            minLength: 1
function checkType<T extends keyof TypeofMap>(value: unknown, ...types: [T, ...T[]]): value is TypeofMap[T] {
    let valueType = value === null ? 'null' : typeof value;
    //      set is not more efficient
    //      as requires cuz types is T[] but needed is (keyof TypeofMap)[] or string[]
    return (types as string[]).includes(valueType)
}
console.log(checkType('asd', 'null')) // false
console.log(checkType('asd', 'null', 'string')) // true
console.log(checkType('asd', 'string')) // true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using a map is a good idea. Also the simplification using includes is nice.